# Camping is splitting URLs at question marks

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, url, camping, markaby

Here's my problem:

[Camping](https://camping.github.io/camping.io/) is splitting urls at question marks.

So if we have some code like this:

```
Camping.goes :CodeLine
module CodeLine::Controllers
 class Index
  def get
   render :index
  end
 end
class TextEntered < R '/(.*)'
  def get(textStringEntered)
   "#{textStringEntered}"
  end
 end
end
module CodeLine::Views
 def index
  html do
   head do
    title "Uh Oh"
   end
   body do
    text "Looks like you got to the index"
    br
    br
    form :name => "input" do
     input :type => "text", :name => "text"
     input :type => "submit", :value => "Submit"
    end
   end
  end
 end
end
```

Run `camping path/to/file`
After going to `localhost:3301` in your browser and entering some text in the text field and hitting submit, you should see everything after the slash, but instead it splits the url at the question mark and because it thinks there is nothing after the slash, it takes you to the index.

Question:
Is it possible to set up `input` so it does not use a question mark, or can I make camping not split at the question mark?

Appendix A
Tested in
1. Google Chrome
2. Firefox
3. Safari

Comment: The question mark is a special character in a URL indicating everything before it is the path and every after is the query string. Is this how you construct the url, or are you trying to access a resource that includes a question mark in the name? If it's the latter, try encoding replacing the question marks with the encoding `%3F`.

Comment: @Zach Kemp - Can I construct the URL without the question mark? E.G. example.com/text=foobarbazqux instead of example.com/?text=foobarbazqux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route only matches the *path* of the URL:

```
https://example.com/hello/world?a=this&b=hello&c=world#nice
^       ^          ^            ^                      ^
Schema  Host       Path         Query parameters       Fragment
```

In Camping you get access to the query parameters through `@input`:

```
@input.a # => "this"
@input.b # => "hello"
@input.c # => "world"
```

Query parameters are more like "options" that you can pass to the controller. For example, you don't want to have a separate controller to handle "sorting by name" and "sorting by date", so instead you use query parameters:

```
class Search
  def get
    query = @input.q || "*"
    page = (@input.page || 1).to_i
    sort = @input.sort || "name"
    @results = fetch_results_from_database_or_something(query, page, sort)
    render :search
  end
end
```

That way, all of these works:

```
/search?query=hello  # Page 1, sort by name
/search?page=5       # Page 5, sort by name, search for everything
/search?query=cars&page=4&sort=date
```

Comment: Still goes to index unless an action is specified for the form and the action is routed to the "Search" controller. Not a big issue.